# Get the Windows ProductID via registry, in JAVA

Tags: java

How do I get the Windows ProductID via registry in Java? The only way I tried is via:

```
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("reg query \"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion\" /v ProductId");
```

which returns null or error.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/585804/accessing-windows-registry and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/62289/read-write-to-windows-registry-using-java for some great tips on how to access the Windows registry.

Answer (score 0):

I used the same way to get the Windows ProductID.
It's worked for me on jdk_1.6.0.26 (x64), but it hasn't on jdk_1.6.0.06 (x86), because I've installed Win7x64.

PD: I used the implementation of WinRegistry from [read/write to Windows Registry using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62289/read-write-to-windows-registry-using-java) and it works if you considering above comment.