# Check Powershell is available in Java

Tags: java, windows, powershell

Is it possible for me to check if Powershell is installed on a computer using Java. I know how to invoke a powershell script, and I can check whether the OS is Windows XP or later, but I'd prefer to check if `powershell.exe` exists or something?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple solution is to check if path `%WINDIR%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe` exists. There is a handy method `java.io.File.Exists()` for that.

Another way is to query the registry. Should Powershell be present, there will be key `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PowerShell`. The naive approach will launch `reg.exe` via `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()` and read its output. More complex way would be based on [JNI/JNA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/585804/accessing-windows-registry), which on Windows provides access to the registry.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The first option would probably be the easiest way, but what if the user has a different version installed?... Would the registry key always be the same regardless of version?

Comment: @Andy Shouldn't be a problem. MS realized that hard-coding version to path is stupid, so all Powershell versions are [installed in v1.0 directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5415259/why-is-powershell-2-0-installed-in-the-same-location-as-powershell-1-0).

Comment: Ah interesting. I'm glad MS realised that! Thanks for clarifying it. Is there anyway to get the `%WINDIR%` in Java?

Comment: It's not that hard coding the version was a stupid idea - powershell 2.0 was originally going to be a side by side install.